# Anomaly in Faraday's constant measurements

Tags: electrochemistry, reference-request

I was reading someone's biography, where the writer stated his early interest in Faraday's constant  measurements (this is set six decades ago). My understanding was that Faraday constant is a true constant but it turns out it is not or it was not considered a true constant for a long time. Different experimental measurements give different results, and the reasons were not fully understood yet! As per the biography, the difference was due to fundamental reasons. Now we are talking about very very small differences but in the world of constants this is not normal. In order to further see the status, as per the author NIST used to state *two* values for the Faraday's constant [Link to the essay on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332353420_ON_THE_DIFFERENCE_OF_THE_VALUES_THE_FARADAY_CONSTANT)

> The Faraday constant as a fundamental physical value has its peculiar
> features, which make it standing out of the other physical
> constants. According to the official documents of NIST [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332353420_ON_THE_DIFFERENCE_OF_THE_VALUES_THE_FARADAY_CONSTANT), this
> constant has two values: $$ \begin{array}{l} \mathrm{F}=96485.33289
>  \pm 0.00059 \mathrm{C} / \mathrm{mole} \text { and } \\
>  \mathrm{F}^{*}=96485.3251 \pm 0.0012 \mathrm{C} / \mathrm{mole} .
>  \end{array} $$ The second value refers to the "ordinary electric
> current". The values are determined according to different
> experimental techniques. The difference amounts $0.000008 \%$, which
> is a tiny difference, however, such a discrepancy is not
> characteristic for other physical constants.

The author's link to NIST is no longer valid, and today the Faraday's constant value is **stated to be exact** on the NIST website. This change must be fairly recent, but no textbook of physical chemistry, new or old ever stated this problem of getting different results by different methods. Has anyone seen this point in mainstream books? I never saw that and it is hard to trace this issue. One cannot even do a exact search of "ordinary electric current" associated with Faraday's constant.

Comment: Regarding mentioned different measurement techniques, there can be still some not yet addressed mutual bias/systematic error. Similar case is for Gravitational constant, where measurements have much better precission than reproducibility.

Comment: Interesting. Since the elementary electric charge is now exact by definition, and likewise the Avogadro number, this appears to force the Faraday constant to a single value. Maybe the former two values of the Faraday constant was due to human beings: dueling committees of experts. ;-)

Comment: @EdV, I will probably ask the author, he is alive. It seem this was something fundamental. He mentions that this something fundamental related to the solvation of electron. People may have artificially fixed it just like Carbon-12 to avoid these headaches.